# how do you upload files using cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, cakephp-1.3

Does anyone have an example on how to upload and process files in cakephp 1.3

I'm currently doing some test, without views (print_r), but I can't seem grab the contents of a file. I was able to grab the file name using `$this->param['filename']`, but that's it.

Also, I'm new to cake, but I am working on an old application using the old cakephp framework. Can someone show me the process in uploading a file in cakephp?

I've seen some examples using `$this->data`, but that doesn't yield any results for me.

Comment: Can you post some code from what you've tried?

Comment: Lots of info here when "Google'd" http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/uploading_files_and_images_with_cakephp

Comment: I dont have much code, I just do vardumps/print_r and send the post request myself. Unfortunately when I try to upload a file my `$this->data` returns empty. Are there any dependencies I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1

Create the form like this

```
 echo $this->Form->create('modelname', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
 echo $this->Form->file('fieldname', array('type'=>'file'));
 $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

Step 2
in controller

```
move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['modelname']['fieldname']['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT.'/foldertosave/filename.extension');
```

make sure you have permission to move the file.